# Blender 2.82 Grease Pencil not showing properly after instance

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil

[image]

The instance of grease pencil dissapears in viewport for somereason when I rotate the camera.
I basicly just draw three cubes, put them into one collection and made an instance collection.
Hope my description is clear enough, thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: does it help switching the Stroke depth order to 3D location?

Comment: I tried all sort of solutions but upgrading it to 2.83 solve the problem, it probably just a bug or something in 2.82. Thx for the reply!